# What is the correct syntax for the DB#command method that is replacing the convenience methods in the MongoDB Java client?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, deprecated

Mongo has deprecated some convenience methods in favor of raw commands, as can be seen here:

[http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/com/mongodb/DB.html#addUser(java.lang.String, char[])](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/com/mongodb/DB.html#addUser(java.lang.String,%20char[]))

When trying to update code for this, after verifying that DB#addUser correctly adds a user, I cannot get this to work with #command:

```
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("admin");
db.command("db.createUser( { user: \"" + DatastoreFactory.DEFAULT_MONGO_DB_USERNAME + "\", pwd: \"" + DatastoreFactory.DEFAULT_MONGO_DB_PASSWORD + "\", roles: [] } )");
```

This results in the following response:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "no such cmd: db.createUser( { user: \"my_username\", pwd: \"my_password\", roles: [] } )" , "code" : 59 , "bad cmd" : { "db.createUser( { user: \"my_username\", pwd: \"my_password\", roles: [] } )" : true}}
```

What's the correct syntax for [#command](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/com/mongodb/DB.html#command(java.lang.String))?

Comment: You're putting in mongo shell syntax for calling the command. You need to construct a `DBObject` with the right syntax, which depends on the command. Check the syntax for the object in [createUser]http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/createUser/#dbcmd.createUser).

Comment: I noticed that was possible, but there is a version of #command that takes a String.  Why wouldn't mongo shell syntax work there?  http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.12/com/mongodb/DB.html#command(java.lang.String)

Comment: Because it's not the syntax for a command. That version of the function is a convenience for executing simple database commands that just require a command object like `{ "cmd" : "name of command" }`.

Comment: I see. What's an example of such a command?